# Magento Including External library

Tags: magento-1.7, class

I have tried Joreon Vermeulen's method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417394/how-to-add-a-3rd-party-library-to-magento to autoload classes but to no avail. Now in my custom autoloader I get the class 'SnsClient.php' but this does not help Magento get the path. I can hardcode it for this particular file but then SnsClient.php uses a file in another folder. Magento is giving can't find error.  I understand that I have to only find a way to get these files path but I have zero ideas about it. Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put your classes in the `lib` folder but just make sure they follow the naming convention.  `Class_Name_Here` maps to the file `Class/Name/Here.php` relative to the lib folder

Comment: Yup that is what I ended up doing, should have updated question. Thanks anyways. I just had to add this in my helper function:                     include_once 'aws-autoloader.php';use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;  to use SQS. Of course, I had to copy files to lib folder first. Asked a stupid question.