# How to solve Error in file including in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to include a file to my custom module observer.

I added my file folder to **lib** folder.

In my observer i called like below

```
require_once 'MailchimpAPI/MCAPI.class.php';//this is workig fine

//I want to call another file

require_once 'Mailerlite/vendor/autoload.php';//this is not working
```

both folders are in same path

**\lib\MailchimpAPI**

**\lib\Mailerlite**

Can any one tell me what is wrong here.I want to implement **Mailerlite** to my magento registration.

Comment: try with this require_once  Mage::getBaseDir('lib').DS.'Mailerlite'.DS.'vendor'.DS.'autoload.php';

Comment: it return false ?  or autoload not working ? check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417394/how-to-add-a-3rd-party-library-to-magento) and [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28954/magento-including-external-library)